# Swift CNContact did changed when app is not active

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

**Update:**
Ok i will explain again i want to know if the phone contacts changed not my data

is there a way to know if contacts were changed without looping all contacts while the app were close

Notification.name.CNContactStoreDidChange work only after app is lunched

Note:
android version is broudcastreceiver notify you for that change even if your app is killed

Comment: my data wont change but i want to know if contacts changed with out looping it to save the work for loading contacts and checking for change

Comment: Ok i will explain again i want to know if the phone contacts changed not my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. In iOS, apps do not support operations that happen when your app is inactive. Thus it is impossible for something like a contact changing to be registered in your app when it is in this inactive state.

The only way that your app can receive data is for example if it comes from an external source (i.e. an online notification) or if you have a time-specific notification that is pre-set when your app is running.

In order to check for something like this you would have to manually search through the contacts upon app startup.

You can see these answers for more details: [Broadcast receiver / service in Android vs. iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770566/broadcast-receiver-service-in-android-vs-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Can iOS receive broadcasts like Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213125/can-ios-receive-broadcasts-like-android)

Comment: No problem :) happy to help